# IllegalStateException when using DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I just started to use DialogFragment from the android support library and find it extremely annoying so far. I have some custom AsyncTasks that are called from different places in my app. There are two occasions when I run into problems with the DialogFragments:

1. When debugging and the screen turns off
2. When I want to open a FragmentDialog from onActivityResult()

Both, at least I think, are fairly common situations, and in both cases I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

This is how my AsyncTasks are structured:

```
private class UploadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Image> {
    private ProgressDialogFragment dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        dialog = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(fm, "ProgressDialogFragment");
    }

    @Override
    protected Image doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Image result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I know i could set a setting that prevents the screen from going to sleep while debugging and i could set a flag in onActivityResult() and then open the dialog in onStart(), but that is not really what I'm looking for. Are there any better solutions??

Thanks
Simon

Comment: This is the one of the most annoying problems I have encountered in Android development. The deprecated dialog APIs did not have this problem. All the workarounds are so ugly. I still could not find a clean solution to this problem.

Comment: Me neither. I'm still waiting for someone showing me a clean solution :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an anwser on this other question: [Show DialogFragment from onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114324/show-dialogfragment-from-onactivityresult)

Basically a [bug in the compatibility library](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23761).

Answer (score 5):

use `dialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();` instead of `dialog.dismiss();`