# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState - DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have overriden the onSavedInstanceState and removed the super, i am not doing any transactions, let alone transactions in volatile functions or async ones.

I am calling it in a custom callback 'onUserExistsListener'

```
        @Override
        public Boolean userExists(Boolean exists) {
            if (exists) {


            }
            else
            {
             AlertDialogFragment Frag = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(0, null);
             Frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "warndialog");
            }
   };
```

Have tried everything suggested in the other SO questions and still found no solution? Anyone?

code:

```
AlertDialogFragment Frag = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(0, null);
 Frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "warndialog");
```

The process:

OnCreate: (LoadNames function)

LoadNames Callback -> Show dialog.

Further:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        add_name_to_db();
    }
```

function:

```
public void add_name_to_db() {
        Details.checkNameExists(user_txt.getText().toString());
        Details.setOnUserExistsListener(new onUserExistsListener() {

            @Override
            public Boolean userExists(Boolean exists) {

                if (exists) 
                    {

                    } else {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                AlertDialogFragment Frag = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(0, null);
                                Frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "warndialog");

                            }

                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is not a valid KIK username",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return exists;
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question some more?

Comment: Are you not calling super.onCreate()? You have to do that.

Comment: The question is not very clear, you should show where are you calling `onUserExistsListener`. Also, you don't need to override `onSavedInstanceState`. Maybe this blog post can help you understand better why this Exception occurs and how to avoid it -> http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: @rubenlop88 Code added! It must have to do with the call back somehow, i just cant figure out why.

Comment: Are you getting a stacktrace in the log, is it crashing? If so amend your question... :)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState at the 'Frag.show'

Comment: Are you calling finish () some where?

Comment: OP - please include the full stacktrace... to save us all from guessing...

Comment: The callback is being called "later on", specifically after the activity has been destroyed or in your case, saved/hidden.

Comment: "I have overriden the onSavedInstanceState and removed the super, i am not doing any transactions, let alone transactions in volatile functions or async ones." -> The question is more rather: WHY ARE YOU DOING THIS?

Comment: In an attempt to find a solution, they we're not already implemented and have since been reversed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show DialogFragment from onActivityResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114324/show-dialogfragment-from-onactivityresult)

Answer (score 6):

By calling `Frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "warndialog");`, **you are in fact performing a fragment transaction** (see [show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29)).

If the activity's onSaveInstanceState() method has been called, an IllegalStateException will be thrown when you try to show the dialog. You need to change your code to ensure that when you show the dialog fragment, you do so after the activity state has been restored (i.e., onPostResume()). See this [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information.

You can also commit the transaction allowing state [loss](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss%28%29);

Comment: Unfortunately, commiting allowing stateloss leaves me with : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Comment: If the activity has been destroyed then you can't attach a fragment to it.Either, change to a regular dialog or ensure you commit with the activity alive and when the activity's state has been restored.

Comment: I've made an alternative solution to DialogFragment, that can avoid this exception : https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/DialogShard

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You need to call the super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState) in onCreate(). It just won't work without it.

---

onSaveInstanceState() occurs when the activity is finishing. It's too late to stop and show UI there.

When do you want this code to run? When the back button is pressed maybe?

Put your code in onBackPressed() for that.

[Android: Proper Way to use onBackPressed() with Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed)

**EDIT** If you want the code to run at the beginning of an activity, as you mention in another comment. Don't use onSaveInstanceState(). **Put your code in onCreate() or onResume().**

Comment: I'm not using saved instance state what so ever, im trying to display a dialog in a normal function when the activity is nowhere near the point of going on pause or into the saved instance.

Comment: You need to call the super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState) in onCreate(). It just won't work without it.

Comment: I'm already doing that. Sorry if i'm confusing you some how? All have another look at it now, and see if i can shed some light on it with fresh mind.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how your callback is working, you may need to run those lines of code on the UI Thread, like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        AlertDialogFragment Frag = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(0, null);
        Frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "warndialog");

    }

});
```